# Is it possible to set dynamic country code before controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

http://www.a2znewspaper.com
 This is my website developed by Codeigniter. By this website i am viewing newspaper country wise. When anyone select country from dropdown list as his/her wish, then i've viewed newspaper including this country.

Now i want to set URL based on country code. such as when a user select "Bangladesh" then i want to make url like " http://www.a2znewspaper.com/BD ". is it possible?

All of wrok has been completed, if i change this url, is it will effect on anything?

Comment: you can use routes in codeigniter but it depends on how you have coded for each country

Comment: but country code is dynamic. say, when user select United States from dropdown list URL will http://www.a2znewspaper.com/US. is it possible to create dynamic URL using route?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035955/remap-or-uri-routing-in-codeigniter

Comment: i want to use second segment as controller

Comment: you have to have general name like newspaper/countryname and map it to that function name

Comment: ys. this way it's work. but i want to country name before newspaper like as .com/bd/newspaper

Comment: yes that is possible but you will have to map country controller name to remap but you will have to create different controller for each country !!!!

Comment: there have around 226 country. how can it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a lot of solutions. I will give some of them, which I used in my old project on CodeIgniter. In index.php I wrote the rules that work with the first segment in the transmitted URL. If this language (in your case - the country) - in this case the language of the URL removed, because language actually becomes the name of the controller.
Another alternative - you can try to write rules for URL with the country.